# Eclipse : Ignore warnings for a certain type of file but keep color syntaxing

Tags: eclipse, file, eclipse-pdt

I have some .tpl files in my PHP project and I want Eclipse to keep HTML color syntaxing but not to check if the syntax (if .tpl has errors or warnings) is correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve this by going to the Problems view, click on the down triangle (upper right corner of the view) and selecting "Configure Contents...". A new window will open which will allow you to configure which warnings/errors to show.